# Why should we use event keyword though the app works without it?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm still having difficulty in understanding the difference between using the event keyword or not **in action**. For example, if we remove the `event` keyword in the following example, everything works just fine. Why do we need it if it works? I can still produce something to be consumed by subscribers. I'm working on .Net 6 if it is necessary to be known.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Order
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class FoodOrderingService
{
    public delegate void FoodPreparedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
    public event FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPrepared;

    public void PrepareOrder(Order order)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Preparing your order '{order.Item}', please wait...");
        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        OnFoodPrepared();
    }

    protected virtual void OnFoodPrepared()
    {
        FoodPrepared?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}

public class AppService
{
    public void OnFoodPrepared(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AppService: your food is prepared.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var order = new Order { Item = "Pizza with extra cheese" };

        var orderingService = new FoodOrderingService();
        var appService = new AppService();
        //var mailService = new MailService();

        orderingService.FoodPrepared += appService.OnFoodPrepared;
        //orderingService.FoodPrepared += mailService.OnFoodPrepared;

        orderingService.PrepareOrder(order);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beyond jmcilhinney's answer, it's good to be explicit.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama but why in this case (: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to highlight some of the differences.

For the sake of simplicity let's have this code:

```
public delegate void FoodPreparedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
public class FoodOrderingService 
{
   public event FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPreparedEvent;
   public FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPrepared;
}
```

```
var service = new FoodOrderingService();

//DOES COMPILE
service.FoodPrepared = new FoodPreparedEventHandler((_, ___) => {});
service.FoodPrepared(null, null);

//DOES NOT COMPILE
service.FoodPreparedEventHandler = new FoodPreparedEventHandler((_, ___) => {}); 
service.FoodPreparedEvent(null, null);
```

- An `event` can't be re-assigned (only `-=` or `+=` operators can be used)
- An `event` can't be invoked outside of the class

+1 In an interface you can't define a field, but you can define an event

```
public interface IFoodOrderingService
{
   event FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPreparedEvent;
   FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPrepared; //DOES NOT COMPILE
}
```

---

[Dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fPjUZZ)

Comment: Thank you. +1, however, 'overridden' keyword a trifle confusing. Instead, 'reassign' is better off.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire True, corrected :D

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `event` keyword in that code then you are left with this:

```cs
public FoodPreparedEventHandler FoodPrepared;
```

so that is a public field and behaves like any other field. Yes, you can still invoke the delegate from within the class but you're not limited to that, as you are with events. This is from the documentation for the `event` keyword, which you should already have read:

> Events are a special kind of multicast delegate that can only be
> invoked from within the class (or derived classes) or struct where
> they are declared (the publisher class). If other classes or structs
> subscribe to the event, their event handler methods will be called
> when the publisher class raises the event.

If it was a field, you could replace any existing delegates from anywhere you could access it and you could also invoke those existing delegates from the outside too. With an event, you can do neither.

Comment: **Would you mind please showing with a minimal code example** according to the saying _you say that you could replace any existing delegates from anywhere you could access it and you could also invoke those existing delegates from the outside too. With an event, you can do neither._ ?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire, why would you need me to provide an example of how a public field works? You already know how to get or set a field. The type makes no difference to that.

Comment: because you are too experienced person as far as I consider, even with your one keypress I may learn a new thing so I don't want to miss the chance (:

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire, there's nothing to learn. A field is a field is a field. If a field is public then you can get the object it refers to and use it, regardless of what type it is. If the type is a delegate then you can get that object and use it. It is a field like any other. You know how a field works. Stop trying to make it more complex than it is.

Comment: ok sir how you wish. Thank you for your help.